# Query or die with specific explanation?

Tags: php, oracle

I'm trying to do a query that dies which returns too many values, however, I don't want to manually specify it like what it is shown.

```
oci_execute($searchSQL) or die ("Unable to execute query as there are too many values\n");
```

However, it is not always this case that it returns too many value. How do I print out the actual problem? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by 'dies which returns too many values'? 

die in this expression will be executed only if oci_execute returns false value, like null, false or empty array.

Comment: @Baldrs Ok, for this case, this search query returns a false because it returns too many values. "ORA-00913: too many values". There may be some other search query that returns false due to some other reason. I can't possibly print all the reason as returning too many values.. How do I print the problems based on the actual problem?

Comment: You can use `oci_error` to print last error if `oci_execute` returned false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
oci_execute($searchSQL) or die (oci_error());
```

....but using die to report an error condition is not very tidy.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for this. It is not meant for public use. =)